# Openpyxl - Error after convert an image to excel spreadsheet possible problem with styles.xml

Tags: python, excel, xml, openpyxl

I'm trying to use a python script to convert an image (*.jpg) to the background color of an Excel's spreadsheet. According to the following photo:

[image: Excel]

**Full Python script:**

```
import openpyxl
from PIL import Image

def image_to_excel(file, output, percentage):

    # Open picture and create a workbook instance
    im = Image.open(file)
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active

    # Resize image with spreadsheet's columns
    width, height = im.size
    cols = width * percentage/100
    print('Old image size: ' + str(im.size))
    imgScale = cols/width
    newSize = (int(width*imgScale), int(height*imgScale))
    im = im.resize(newSize)

    # Get new picture's dimensions
    cols, rows = im.size
    print('New image size: ' + str(im.size))

    # Spreadsheet's cell: height = 6 and width = 1
    for i in range(1, rows):
        sheet.row_dimensions[i].height = 0.6
    for j in range(1, cols):
        column_letter = openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(j)
        sheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = 0.0625

    # Convert image to RGB
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

    # Formatting cell's color 
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for j in range(1, cols):
            c = rgb_im.getpixel((j, i))
            rgb2hex = lambda r,g,b: f"ff{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"
            c = rgb2hex(*c)
            sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = " "
            customFill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(start_color=c, end_color=c, fill_type='solid')
            sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).fill = customFill

    # Save workbook
    #im.close()
    #rgb_im.close()
    wb.save(output) 
    wb.close()


# Export
image_to_excel('jangada.jpg', 'final.xlsx', 100)
```

The problem is when I tried to change the images, like this one: https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/09/croatia-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-to-visit-plitvice-lakes.jpg and after run the code I got the error:

[image: Error]

The translation is something like that:

*Excel was able to open teh file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.*

*Removed Records: Style from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)*

*Repaired Records: Informations about the cell part of /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml*

I'm using excel 2013. Anyone knows how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rgb2hex` isn't working as you intended, remove the `ff` from it, I think that's whats breaking your code.

Your func:

```
>>>rgb2hex = lambda r,g,b: f"ff{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"
>>>rgb2hex(120,120,120)
ff787878
```

The output should be `787878`.

```
>>>rgb2hex = lambda r,g,b: f"{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"
>>>rgb2hex(120,120,120)
787878
```

Comment: I tried to remove it, but the error persists. Have you tested the code on your excel? I think could be some excel version problem or limitation.

Comment: @LuísEduardo there is some hard limit in Excel, when I change the image size (25%) and cell sizes to row=0.8, col=0.1 it does work.

Comment: @LuísEduardo An image size of `(313,209) `with cell size of `(0.7,0.075)` was almost the biggest I could achieve, more than that and Excel gives an error or the grid is too small.

Comment: Which also makes sense as 0.75 Point == 1 Pixel (As well as 0.08 in Column width)

Comment: Yeah, I think it's excel limit. What's your excel version ?

Comment: I think that it depends of the number of colors on the image. I tried this one: https://github.com/Nekose/Mouseomate/blob/master/images/mona.jpg with image scale of 200% and doesn't have any problem on excel file after code execution.

Comment: @LuísEduardo, maybe, I understand that at least its working for now :)